# Are separate "admin" accounts overkill?

Tags: security, users, administrator

According to [this article](http://spreadprivacy.com/linux-privacy-tips-1dc956657357), the author recommends *not* using an "administrator" account for day-to-day computing, due to security reasons... Way back when I used Microsoft Windows-based operating systems, I would use a separate "administrator" account for this very reason.

But I have always been under the impression that this is less of an issue under Linux-based operating systems (particularly Ubuntu, which I single-boot these days), and hence it's only since I read this article that I have switched to using separate "administrator"/"user" accounts.

But is this necessarily a good security practice? Or is it overkill for day-to-day computing in a home environment?

Comment: It's a good security practice for some, and an overkill for others. One size doesn't fit all here, so It depends on the user case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The idea behind "sudo" is traceability and accountability. You use 1 account per person per role.  When you have 1 admin account used by 10 people ...

... you will never find the culprit when someone screws up. 
... you will need to change the password and notify 9 people of that change.

On a single user machine not so much an issue but Ubuntu/Linux is a multi-user system so we inherited a few of those rules onto the desktop.

> Or is it overkill for day-to-day computing in a home environment?

No, nowadays it is a necessity. Look at that ransomware attack last May. And the ransomware that is hitting servers at this moment. There are also rootkits that try to find holes to get onto system (also not really a problem for you and me since our systems are not worth breaching ;) ).

The user/admin role separation is just 1 of the security measures to prevent unwanted direct access to your system (both physically or remotely). It will not stop someone stealing your machine and rebooting.

It is good practice to keep the current safeguards active.